# 2100 error on lenovo e550 laptop, But linux lives boots each time

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, thinkpad, livecd

Before mark this question as duplicate **Please read it completely**.
I have a `lenovo thinkpad e550` and I encounter this error in boot time:

```
2100: Detection error on HDD0 (Main HDD)
Press Esc to continue.
```

I read about this problem in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/734073/2100-detection-error-on-hdd0-black-screen-error-lenovo-thinkpad-carbon-x1) on same site. But my case is a little different. I Asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946415/xubuntu-different-boot-results-sometimes-succeed-most-of-error-times-attempt) on askubuntu about this about two weeks ago. heynnema's solution worked this two weeks, But again the problem happend.

In My case I can Boot `Live Linux` on `USB` and `DVD` very well each time. I live Linux I tested the hard partitions they were working well. I could write and read on them. I reinstalled my `ubuntu`. But the problem persists and I can just boot live Linux and after that I can retrieve my hard drive data in it. (I tried windows bootable disk, it even not booted)

Can Bios be the problem? Cause I really Don't think `Hard Disk` has any problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Am not sure why this happens!!!!**

After I open my laptop, (just first part for `HDD` and `RAMS`), I take out the hard drive and place it back again! It worked! I hadn't any other problem with boot since last month!